# Jquery menu shift/overlap div section images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web programming, so any suggestion would be great asset for me.

I tried to create menu and image sliding using jquery, but that menu overlap with images in chrome and shift div section in IE.

Code http://jsfiddle.net/bM9vR/3/

Results
http://jsfiddle.net/bM9vR/3/embedded/result/

i also attached sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" >

body{background:#534741;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;} 
ul, li{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}  

.menu_head{border:1px solid #998675;}  
.menu_body {width:184px;border-right:1px solid #998675;border-bottom:1px solid #998675;border-left:1px solid #998675;}
.menu_body li{background:#493e3b;}
.menu_body li a{color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; padding:10px; display:block;} 
.menu_body li.alt{background:#362f2d;}  
.menu_body {display:none; width:184px;border-right:1px solid #998675;border-bottom:1px solid #998675;border-left:1px solid #998675;} 
.menu_body li a:hover{padding:15px 10px; font-weight:bold;}  
                                                #slideshow { 
                                                            margin: 50px auto; 
                                                            position: relative; 
                                                            width: auto; 
                                                            height: auto; 
                                                            padding: 10px; 
                                                            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
                                                        }

                                                        #slideshow > div { 
                                                            position: absolute; 
                                                            top: 10px; 
                                                            left: 10px; 
                                                            right: 10px; 
                                                            bottom: 10px; 
                                                        }

</style>  

<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
$("ul.menu_body li:even").addClass("alt");
$('img.menu_head').click(function () {  
$('ul.menu_body').slideToggle('medium');
});

$('ul.menu_body li a').mouseover(function () { 
$(this).animate({ fontSize: "14px", paddingLeft: "20px" }, 50 ); 
});

$('ul.menu_body li a').mouseout(function () {
$(this).animate({ fontSize: "12px", paddingLeft: "10px" }, 50 );
});

$(function(){
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
});

});    
</script>  
</head>
<body style="margin:auto;">
<div style="width:1000px; height:600px; margin:20px;">
<div style="width:auto; height:100px">

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNrzbTsg60SbbpFVCI-Mt7gq6V6W3lSvFQznvZiuRUAP1Rh1pt" width="184" height="32" class="menu_head" alt="Click"/><br>  
<ul class="menu_body">
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></li>  
</ul>  
</div>
<div style="width:auto; height:100px; background-color:white;">
<div id="maindiv221">
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxhQOGp29MxjxwtL97VTm2lzyYYvOSLoOiMo3uWJFdBm91gMJjPvSD7Ag" alt="1">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvTJ-sdmw9EjrrL7j9izN3IavFusBzfvlc_Ow9as6TNfdfvr88" alt="2">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTt4CqLzoaI9ehHYZs-B1eo8X-5qoMdaiRd6juWKmoFfwrmoK8Urg" alt="3">
   </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
  ​
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.menu_body` class add this code in your `CSS` section

```
z-index: 999999;
position:relative;
```

Z-index of menu must be bigger than in other elements. Elements with bigger z-index, are "closer" to us. Check this link about z-index: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp
NOTE: z-index only works in elements with non-static position. (relative, absolute and fixed position).

Comment: thanks , zindex solved my problem in chrome, but i am not able to solve problem in IE, it shift image div down to fit menu. (if i add this sample code to normal html file and open that html file.)